# Relate an architecture to a Data Warehouse System Architecture

Tags: architecture, data-warehouse

Below you find from the company EC4U an architecture
for a a data warehouse system. (OBI stands for Oracle Business Intelligence).
And I want to relate this architecture to the data warehouse system reference architecture
(see the first image) Which parts of the EC4U architecture fulfill the task(s) of which
components of the reference architecture?

I tried this, below you can find my solution. Is it right? Is something missing?

**Data Warehouse System Architecture**

[image]

**EC4U Architecture**
[image]

**Solution**

```
Reference Architecture      |        EC4U Architecture
=========================================================================                 
Data Sources                |        OLTP Application Server (Operational Systems)
Data Warehouse              |        OLAP DWH 
Staging Area                |        Database Server
Transformation              |        ETL Server
DW Manager                  |        Information Server
Repository                  |        Config Files, RPD, Catalog, Log Files
Metadata Manager            |        BI Server
```

**Definitions**

*Functional Components*

- Data Warehouse Manager: Central component, starts, monitors and controls all
  processes from extraction of data from the sources to analysis.
- Monitors: detect and report to the data warehouse manager updates in the data
  sources that are relevant for the DW. There is usually one Monitor per data source.
- Extractors: select and transport data from the sources to the Staging Area
- Transformators: Before loading into the Basic Database, data must be transformed
  into a homogeneous internal format to be comparable => unify, integrate, consolidate,
  aggregate, and supplement extracted data in the Staging Area.
- Loading Components: Load acquired and transformed data from the Staging Area
  to the Basic Database and from there finally into the DW
- Analysis Components: Provide analysis and presentation of data in the DW.
- Metadata Manager: A database application that controls the metadata management
  of the DWS. It provides an interface for read and write access to the repository
  where the metadata are stored.

*Data components*

- Data sources: Operational systems with detailed data some or all of which are fed
  to the DW
- Staging Area: intermediate storage area where data is transformed and integrated
  for the DW. Not necessarily a database system.
- Basic Database: A database system with integrated data from which the DW is
  updated periodically. Unlike in the DW, the data in the Basic Database can be changed
  and deleted. It contains the data that has changed since the last loading of the
  DW. Not every DWS has a Basic Database.
- Repository: contains the metadata of the DW (comparable to a data dictionary).
  Information from the respective data dictionaries of the source databases is also
  imported into the Repository.
- Data Warehouse (DW): a database with historical data designed in a model suited
  to analytic needs.

Answer (score 0):

Database server (RDBMS, OLTP, Excel,Files) is the Data Source.
ETL Server represents the gray area un the 1st diagram (Extraction, Transformation, Loading, Staging Arda, etc.)
DWH is the Data Warehouse.

Both diagram elements don't match with one-to-one correspondance.